# How to build standalone Intl extension from bundled source

Tags: php, rpm

For a long time I've maintained my own package of the PECL [Intl extension](http://php.net/manual/en/intl.installation.php) for PHP 5, but upgrading now to PHP 7 I'm unable to build the extension that's bundled with PHP.

With a clean installation I do the following from the base of the PHP source directory:

```
cd ext/intl
phpize
./configure --with-icu-dir=/usr
make
```

Configure completes OK, but Make throws a load of Zend errors that I can't comprehend. The final message reads `make: *** [intl_convertcpp.lo] Error 1`.

I've pasted [the rest of the output here](https://pastebin.com/raw/xqUDERYV).

I've tried this with various versions of the ICU library, and that doesn't seem to affect the outcome. It has no problem finding the library. Are there other options I need to specify for the build to complete?

---

Please note: I'm purposefully building this as a standalone extension so I can use a custom (more recent) ICU installation. My PHP runtime comes from Remi repo but its [Intl package](http://remi.mirrors.cu.be/enterprise/7/php72/x86_64/repoview/php-intl.html) depends on ICU 50.1.2 from the CentOS 7 base repo. However, even with that base repo version installed (and in the normal location), I still can't build the extension using the standard method shown above.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of googling I found the [answer here](https://github.com/nginx/unit/issues/47).

I needed a newer version of the GCC compiler. The CentOS 7 updates repo has v4.8.5 but the `__builtin_ssubl_overflow` error message indicates that I needed at least v5.

With the help of this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36327805/how-to-install-gcc-5-3-with-yum-on-centos-7-2) I got a newer compiler by installing [devtoolset-7](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/devtoolset-7/) then building like this:

```
cd ext/intl
phpize
CXX=/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/g++ \
 ./configure --with-icu-dir=/usr
make
```

Success